# How to calculate Spearman's rank correlation matrix using scipy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, correlation

I have numpy array as

```
allseries = [
[4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 7.0, 4.0, 6.0], [5.0, 6.1, 7.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 9.9], [74.0, 16.0, 82.0, 54.0, 2.0, 12.0, 5.0, 57.0, 4.0, 96.0], [5.0, 6.1, 7.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 9.9]
]
allseries = np.array(allSeries)
```

where each individual list is a set of values. How Could I calculate Spearman's rank correlation coefficient using 
`scipy.stats.spearmanr()`

I tried using `scipy.stats.spearmanr(allSeries)` but it does not works.
I do not want to use pandas or any other library.

Comment: scipy.stats.spearmanr(np.transpose(allSeries))[0]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide 2 parameters, from your allseries:

```
scipy.stats.spearmanr(allseries[0],allseries[1])
Out[10]: SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.043082021842766452, pvalue=0.90593280122949815)
```

Comment: Aren't there any way to directly calculate the spearman's correlation matrix similar to np.corrcoef(allSeries)

Comment: I think I got it scipy.stats.spearmanr(np.transpose(allSeries))[0]